# How do I assemble an APRS packet in Javascript/Apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, weather

I have an Apps Script project that collects readings from my weather station every 1 minute. If I were to, for example, update [the Windy API](https://community.windy.com/topic/8168/report-your-weather-station-data-to-windy) with my weather station data, I could:

```js
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://stations.windy.com/pws/update/XXX-API-KEY-XXX?winddir=230&windspeedmph=12&windgustmph=12&tempf=70&rainin=0&baromin=29.1&dewptf=68.2&humidity=90');
```

I would like to upload this data to [CWOP](http://www.wxqa.com/). They describe the need to assemble an APRS packet, and [list a few softwares](http://www.wxqa.com/activecwd.html) that have this functionality built-in. Is assembling an APRS packet via Apps Script possible, and can I send it out to whatever URL endpoint it needs to be sent to via `UrlFetchApp`?

**Edit**: The only hint I could find is [this Python script](https://www.wxforum.net/index.php?topic=36181.0), which building a string? Then sending it to `cwop.aprs.net`?

**Edit 2**: Found [another project that's doing this](https://github.com/acuparse/acuparse/blob/1c06705b0e8aa24ba9fed5392ef02edec99edd27/cron/cron.php#L138), in PHP...

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share the Python example you found as you did not include the link in your question? Also, I believe from the [CWOP examples of data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type) that you could just send a ```.txt``` file and the APRS server could catch it (although I am not too sure, you could try that). Also, from the [content types]() of [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) that you can pass in the fetch options I could not find one for an ```APRS```  packet.

Comment: Whoops! Somehow that got trimmed off, sorry. The documentation is so bad! If there's a way to POST a TXT file to CWOP, then yeah, we could do that with `UrlFetchApp`...

Comment: You can use ```UrlFetchApp.fetch``` for making post requests and sending a payload that can be your text file converted into a blob using ```Utilities.newBlob```. Check out [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) of how to make a post request of a text file using ```UrlFetchApp``` and let me know if this is of any help or if it solves your issue. :D